# Are there pictures of unassembled planes being transported around?

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer

My google-fu is failing me here.

A friend was telling me about the assembly of carbon-fibre planes, and how the huge parts of these need to be transported long distances between countries.

Are there any photos of this?

Comment: Something like [this](http://cdn1.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2012/6/22/220323.jpg)? It's the Airbus Beluga which is used by Airbus to move parts of planes around Europe.

Comment: Or something like [this](http://users.skynet.be/spotterfreak/images/A380transport_02.jpg), a ground transport of the A380 which doesn't fit into the Beluga?

Comment: For Boeing pictures, like [this](http://www.kansas.com/news/business/aviation/zdv48x/picture3606379/ALTERNATES/FREE_960/031010dreamlifter_mh2.jpg.JPG)? It has nothing do to with carbon fiber, and everything to do with aircraft manufacturers having plants spread out over a bunch of places.

Comment: The answer is yes, as in the links posted, since photos at least exist for PR purposes. But I think this would be a better question if it were asking something different, maybe for some details about the transportation that would help get your google-fu started, and answers could include pictures like those posted to satisfy the current question.

Comment: @fooot yeah I agree that it's a marginal question. The original question was 'how are carbon fibre planes made?'

Comment: I'm gonna vote to put this on hold for now, because it's inviting answers of "here's these couple of pictures" and there's no definitive answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have pictures of wing upper cover being handled and transported:

[image]


<sup>(Image Source: www.airbus.com)</sup>

Wing upper cover is biggest single composite component on A350XWB.

Additionaly try google: "wing upper cover A350", "wing lower cover A350". Those are the biggest. And you can see them in various stages in google.

Answer (score 3):

Google: A380 Transport fluvial

[image]